# How can I limit number of bookings in SQL per day to 50 users

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table with columns `id autoincrement, username, datetime, logtime(on update)`
I want to allow only 50 users make a booking per day
and also each user to make a booking once per day everyday.
How can I write my query?
This query I wrote concerning for user once per day

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

if ($con) {
    mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name) or die('Database not found');

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `booker` WHERE `datetime` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

How can I write query to allow only 50 users per day?

Comment: That is business logic and should be in your php code. Not in a sql query

Comment: You will need to add a column to booker, say booked. Each time there is a booking booked is updated to yes and datetime is updated to current time. You also need another table, say bookingcount : bookings and firstbooking. Each time there is a booking bookings count is increased by 1. Update firstbooking column only when the first booking is made. Delete( i.e empty ) the bookingcount table when bookings is = 50. Whenever there is a booking request, check if the booked column for that user is yes AND TIMESTAMPDIFF at datetime is < 24 hours and check also if bookings in bookingcount is < 50

Comment: bookingcount should be emptied when bookings = 50 AND the TIMESTAMPDIFF at firstbooking > 24 hours

Comment: which means that firstbooking data type is datetime

Comment: @hans-könig i have added the table and the column but write me out some php query to clarify me more am just a beginner please thanks

Comment: @hans-könig firstbooking should is default be on update and also the bookings too

Comment: what kind of join will i use to join the two tables together

Answer (score 1):

Try the below script and I changed.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `booker` WHERE DATE(`datetime`) = CURDATE()";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
//get total records
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows>50)
{
    //Today booked orders is completed
}
else
{
    //The booked orders is not completed for today
}
```

Comment: can I use this query to make only 50 users to log in per day